# Reason: Error: Unbound value not__ for bs-jest

Tags: reason, bucklescript, bs-jest

Trying to test a binding of `lit-html` method `html`

```
open Jest;

let write = () => LitHtml.html("<div></div>");

open Expect;

describe("LitHtml", () =>
  test("#html", () =>
    expect(() =>
      write()
    ) |> not_ |> toThrow
  )
);
```

I am told this cryptic error:

```
Error: Unbound value not__
Hint: Did you mean not_?
Jest.Expect.plainPartial('a) => Jest.Expect.invertedPartial('a)
```

But clearly wrote `not_` as it suggests, not `not__`.

My attempted binding:

```
[@bs.module "LitHtml"] [@bs.val]
external html: string => Js.nullable(string) = "html";
let html = htmlStr => html(htmlStr) |> Js.Nullable.toOption;
```

Thanks for any assistance. Just getting started with ReasonML ;)

Answer (score 1):

Seems like this is caused by a largely undocumented change [in Reason 3.3.4](https://github.com/facebook/reason/blob/master/HISTORY.md#334). I think it might hide in PR [#2197](https://github.com/facebook/reason/pull/2197).

`not` is a keyword in OCaml, which is why `Expect.not_` is named such as it is in the first place. And this change seems to "mangle" (ie. translate) `not` in Reason into `not_` in OCaml, and then `not_` to `not__` and so on.

So the solution is simply to replace all instances of `not_` in your code with `not`. OR you can update `bs-jest` to `0.4.7` where I've added `not__` as an alias to `not_`, so you can use either `not` or `not_`.